Next Auth MongoDB adapter stopping status from authenticating
mongoConnect.ts
    import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from "mongodb"

    if (!process.env.MONGO_URI) {
      throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGO_URI"')
    }

    const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI
    const options = {}


    console.log("MongoDB URI:", uri)

    let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      console.log("Running in development mode")

      let globalWithMongo = global as typeof globalThis & {
        _mongoClientPromise?: Promise<MongoClient>
      }

      if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
        console.log("Creating new MongoClientPromise in development mode")

        globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = (async () => {
          console.log("Initializing new MongoClient")
          const client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
          console.log(client.connect( ))
          
          console.log("Connecting to MongoDB")
          await client.connect()

          console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
          return client
        })()
      } else {
        console.log("Using existing MongoClientPromise in development mode")
      }
      clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise
    } else {
      console.log("Running in production mode")

      clientPromise = (async () => {
        try {
          console.log("Initializing new MongoClient")
          const client = new MongoClient(uri, options)

          console.log("Connecting to MongoDB")
          await client.connect()

          console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
          return client
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error)
          throw error
        }
      })()
    }

    // Export the client promise
    console.log("Exporting clientPromise")
    export default clientPromise


route.js
    
  import clientPromise from "../../../libs/mongoConnect";
  import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
  import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
  import { User } from "../../../models/User";
  import NextAuth, {getServerSession} from "next-auth";
  import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
  import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
  import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"

  export const authOptions = {

    secret: process.env.SECRET,
      adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'Credentials',
        id: 'credentials',
        credentials: {
          username: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "test@example.com" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          const email = credentials?.email;
          const password = credentials?.password;

          mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
          const user = await User.findOne({email});
          const passwordOk = user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

          if (passwordOk) {
            return user;
          }

          return null
        }
      })
    ],
  };


  const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

  export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

Basically what is happening is mongoClient() in mongoConnect.js is not connecting and is stuck in pending state when i try to login
so whenever i am using adapter in route it is stopping me from getting logged in since the client.connect() is in pending state
these are terminal logs:
Creating new MongoClientPromise in development mode
Initializing new MongoClient
Promise { pending }
Connecting to MongoDB
Exporting clientPromise
as shown in these logs database is always in connecting to MongoDB state and promise is also always pending meaning client is not getting connected nor throwing err
just know that entire authentication logic is working fine without the adapter part like if i comment it out so the problem lies here
